# Use a callback function/method

Tags: php

Here is what I'm attempting to achieve, but I haven't been able to somehow figure out how to possibly link and spread out the calls.

I have two properties `birthday` and `hire_date` that returns back TODAYS date when the value is blank, when the while loop on top is defined.

---

The following insert inside the while loop defines back as 0000-00-00 which is exactly what I want but I don't want the `birthday` and `hire_date` verification to be defined inside the Importer class:

```php
                $obj = $this->parseLine(utf8_encode($lines[$index]));
                $arr = $this->mapObject($obj);
                $record = $this->getRecord($obj);
                if ($record) {
                    if ($obj->updated_date > $record->updated_date || $mode === 'refresh') {
                        if (empty($obj->birthday)) {
                            $record->fill([
                                'birthday' => ''
                            ]);
                            unset($arr['birthday']);
                        }
                        if (empty($obj->hire_date)) {
                            $record->fill([
                                'hire_date' => ''
                            ]);
                            unset($arr['hire_date']);
                        }
                        $record->fill($arr);
                    } else {
                        $record->timestamps = false;
                    }
                    $record->deleted_at = null;
                } else {
                    $record = $this->createRecord($arr);
                }
                $record->touched_at = $now;
                $record->save();
```

---

What I want to achieve:

Is there anyway that I can break off the following:

```php
                        if (empty($obj->birthday)) {
                            $record->fill([
                                'birthday' => ''
                            ]);
                            unset($arr['birthday']);
                        }
                        if (empty($obj->hire_date)) {
                            $record->fill([
                                'hire_date' => ''
                            ]);
                            unset($arr['hire_date']);
                        }
                        $record->fill($arr);
```

and define the method inside my parser as:

```php
return (object)[
            'birthday' => ['function/method'],
        ];
```

All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fill method inside Eloquent model accepts array as the only argument. Hence, the mapObject method should return an array. The solution to your problem is as follows:

```
public function mapObject($obj)
    {
        return [
            'birthday' => empty($obj->birthday) ?
                '' :
                Carbon::parse($obj->birthday)->format('Y-m-d'),
            'hire_date' => empty($obj->hire_date) ?
                '' :
                Carbon::parse($obj->hire_date)->format('Y-m-d'),
        ];
    }
```

Then, inside Importer class, all you have to do is to make call to fill the object using:

```
$record->fill($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Harry, this works like a charm! - I was definitely overcomplicating things.